# How to increase switch size in kivy language

Tags: python, kivy-language

I am using Switch in my code. But I am not able to change the size of Switch in .kv file. Please someone guide how to change the  size of `Switch`.

I have tried using

```
Switch:
    size_hint: (1,1)
    active: True
```

in order to achieve this but still unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

You should set `size_hint` to `None, None` and then `size` to the values you want.